Are there conditions to finding Sketamari the first time?
Is finding Sketamari before getting its drop, locked to a base game Standard Character, or some other condition?
Like how I couldn't find Random with Menya Moonspell and had to use Zi'Assunta Belpaese to get them?
I walked the way said in guides with Suor Clerici for basically the whole 30 minutes, with the Merchant to mark my starting location, and no Sketamari appeared. I walked:

 South

My last guess is that I have to get the Yellow Sign before I can find Sketamari? Especially given now that I have the Sign myself and the "Find the Drop" achievement is listed.
But, given how far the Sketamari travels, and how thin it is, I could've just missed it every time.

To quote the wiki page:
"Unlike most enemies, it does not spawn as part a wave or map event, but instead can be found naturally due south of The Bone Zone's center."
I did come across it by accident (and got beaten). Sketamari is always at exactly the same horizontal "height" and travels quite a bit horizontally. Coming across it by accident or by walking in the direction of it's travel path is almost impossible. Unless you can somehow determine the exact horizontal "height" and then being lucky enough to go towards it instead of walking from it.
the yellow sign is your best bet as it is the only way to get a question mark on its location.

So you're saying that it does exist even without Yellow Sign, it's just highly unlikely to find.
